# UPDATE script that runs with SQL-Server as well with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have two SQL scripts that are doing exactly the same. 
The first one works just with PostrgeSQL and the second one works just with SQL-Server.

PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE address AS a
SET countrycode = s.isocode
FROM country AS s
WHERE a.idcountry = s.id;
```

SQL-Server:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.countrycode = c.isocode
FROM address AS a
INNER JOIN country AS c
ON a.idcountry = c.id;
```

Is it possible to create a single script with the same functionality that runs on both database systems?

Comment: I guess a co-related sub-query for the assignment should work. But it is going to be a **lot** slower. Something like this: http://hastebin.com/eqilarepex.sql

Comment: If this is one-time job then what's the point? If not then - is this the only scrip in your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE address a
SET countrycode = (
      SELECT s.isocode
      FROM country s
      WHERE a.idcountry = s.id
);
```